# Displaying placeholder image if src is empty

Tags: php

Hey guys I have this code and I am trying to display an image if the `src=""` is empty.

I am using `!empty` to try to display my placeholder image as you can see here:

```
<img src="'.
    (!empty( $cardata["PictureRefs"]))
    ? (explode(',', $cardata["PictureRefs"])[0])
    : "db-content/theme/media/img/no-image.jpg" . '" data-src="'.
      (explode(',', $cardata["PictureRefs"])[0]) .'" alt="'.$cardata["Variant"].'"/> 
<img class="ms-thumb" src="'.
    (!empty( $cardata["PictureRefs"]))
    ? (explode(',', $cardata["PictureRefs"])[0])
    : "db-content/theme/media/img/no-image.jpg" .'" alt="'.$cardata["Variant"].'" />
```

For some reason this isn't working on my page, it just breaks the page.

Any idea where I might be going wrong? I am just left with the external url that the PDO is fetching from the DB displaying in text on the page.

CODE:

```
<?php $src = "db-content/theme/media/img/no-image.jpg";
        if(!empty( $cardata["PictureRefs"])){
        $src = explode(',', $cardata["PictureRefs"])[0];
        }
        $dataSrc = explode(',', $cardata["PictureRefs"])[0]; ?>
            <?php echo '
                <div class="ms-slide">
                    <img src="'.$src.'" data-src="'.$dataSrc.'" alt="'.$cardata["Variant"].'"/>
                    <img class="ms-thumb" src="'.(explode(',', $cardata["PictureRefs"])[0]).'" alt="'.$cardata["Variant"].'" />
                </div>' ?>
```

It just displays the 404 for the image it was trying to receive in the first place.

Comment: This looks and reads *horrible* and it is not DRY. Create at least a function for it or you'll repeat that mess all over the place. "just breaks the page." isn't a proper issue description. Make sure php shows errors and tell us the error.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know what is going wrong, I refactored the code for the first image in order to make it easier to read and help others to understand:

```
$src = "db-content/theme/media/img/no-image.jpg";

if(!empty( $cardata["PictureRefs"])){
    $src = explode(',', $cardata["PictureRefs"])[0];
}

$dataSrc = explode(',', $cardata["PictureRefs"])[0];

echo '<img src="'.$src.'" data-src="'.$dataSrc.'" alt="'.$cardata["Variant"].'"/>';
```

Are you using PHP 5.5 or later? Array dereferencing in this way (from the result of the explode function) requires PHP 5.5 or later.

It may be useful to view the source of the resulting page and post that.

Comment: Thanks for this, I've tried using it however I'm having no luck. I'll add my exact code I am using to the original post, can you see anything that might cause this to not work?